# Is there a term for titles designed for cross-site traffic?

Tags: discussion, site-crossover, terminology, traffic

What term is there for questions like:

1. [How can I tell if a corpse is safe to eat?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4999/how-can-i-tell-if-a-corpse-is-safe-to-eat) (Gaming)
2. [So I was out drinking last night...how do I remove a tattoo?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22862/so-i-was-out-drinking-last-night-how-do-i-remove-a-tattoo) (Gaming)

which generate a lot of traffic from people from other sites going "What the?" at the title?

I've encountered two questions today that seem to be "guilty" of that, and I want to know what to call it.

Comment: [Link bait?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_bait)

Comment: Off-topic: Belongs on English.Stackexchange.com :P

Comment: @Robert: Or maybe [webmasters.se]?

Comment: *Memetic*, perhaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least here on Meta Stack Exchange, the word 'clickbait' seems the most prevalent. Searching for that word in combination with the [hot-questions](/questions/tagged/hot-questions) tag gives [14 results](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22clickbait%22+%5Bhot-questions%5D). It's also a widely used and understood term on the Internet, with definitions in both [reputable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clickbait) and [not-so-reputable](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=clickbait) dictionaries.